# How to put objects in `std::tuple` and take the first item with move-only operations?

Tags: c++, tuples, c++14, move

I use a lambda to put objects of different types in a tuple and pass it to a second lamda to get the first item.
The idea is to only use move-only operations, but the following code still needs a copy to get the first items from the tuple.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

struct foo {
    foo()=default;
    foo(const foo &) { std::cout << "COPY\n"; }
    foo(foo &&) { std::cout << "MOVE\n"; }

};

int main()
{
    auto lst = [](auto ...args) {
        return [tp = std::make_tuple(std::move(args)...)](auto lmb) { return lmb(tp); };
    };

    auto head = [](auto lmb) {
        return lmb([](auto tp) { return std::move(std::get<0>(tp)); });
    };

    foo f ;

    auto lmb = lst(std::move(f),1,2);

    std::cout << std::endl;

    auto r = head(std::move(lmb));
}
```

This produces the following output:

```
MOVE
MOVE

MOVE
COPY
MOVE
```

I don't understand where in the chain this copy takes place.

So the question is:
Is it possible to do this with move-only operations (and how) ?

Comment: Your capture clause must explicitly be an rvalue-reference. In your syntax, it implicitly copies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tuple, `tp`, is copied from here:

```
return lmb(tp);
           ^^
```

to here

```
[](auto tp) { ... }
        ^^
```

The first one needs to be `return lmb(std::move(tp));`

You'll also need to make the lambda `mutable` since captures are `const` by default.

```
[tp = std::make_tuple(std::move(args)...)](auto lmb) mutable { ... };
                                                     ^^^^^^^
```

Comment: also, I think you may need to make the `[tp = ...]` lambda `mutable`

Comment: I did try (before posting) the move operation on the `tp` return type, but it did not work. As you sugested, the lambda was not mutable;  that was indeed the problem. If you add that to the answer, I'm happy to accept